# How do I step into the script of a Data Flow component when debugging an SSIS package in VS 2005?

Tags: debugging, ssis, breakpoints

If I open the script and set a breakpoint, it is ignored.  In fact, if I close and re-open the script, the breakpoint is no longer there.

Even "Stop" commands do not cause it to break.

If I put a break point on the containing Data Flow Task in the Control Flow diagram, it stops, but when I try to step into it, I get the error message: "Unable to step. Not implemented"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, i think is a limitation of SSIS.

For me the best way to "Debug" a Data flow script task is instead of setting up breakpoints, place msgboxes..

Comment: That's not what I wanted to here.  Does this change in 2008?

Answer (score 0):

I hope after setting the breakpoint, you are also saving the script file and then closing it. Please make sure that once you close the script file you need to press the ok button to save the changes you have made in the script used lest it wont save the changes done.